# Limit token and wallet addresses a wallet can interact with?

Tags: solana-program

The title's wording might be a bit awkward hopefully I can explain better.

I want to have Wallet A not be able to interact with anything BUT

-Few Token Addresses ( SOL, USDC, TokenA, TokenB,... Token X) and no other tokens.

-Few Program Addresses, and no others.

The point would be that Wallet A can be trusted that the funds cannot be skimmed but at the same time can be controlled by the owner of Wallet A. I'm not exactly looking for a DAO which has governance just a wallet ( or program ) with restrictions in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answering my own question.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/farms/docs/fund.md

Creating a fund above does all these things, I think I need to fork it for other integrations though.